# Why is Indirect Speech used with an Historic Infinitive in this Quote from Ovid?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Ovid's Fasti 5. 353-4:

> "et monet aetatis specie, dum floreat, uti: contemni spinam, cum cecidere rosae."

> "and she warns that, while it flourishes with the appearance of youth, when the roses fall the thorn is to be despised."

(i) What exactly is "uti" doing here; there's no subjunctive involved, in that clause?

(ii) Why is indirect speech (accusative-[passive] infinitive), "contemni spinam", used with the historic-infinitive cum-clause?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, *moneo* is being used with a simple infinitive, which is *uti*. The ablative *specie* is the object of *uti*.

The colon (after *uti*) is a signal, as it often is, that the speaker is switching into indirect statement (here to represent some of the words that were used in offering the advice/warning).

Also, note that *cecidere* isn't an infinitive but an alternative to *ceciderunt*, the 3rd person plural of the perfect.

> She advises/warns (someone) to use the beauty of the period of life while it flourishes, (saying that) the thorn is thought little of when the roses have fallen.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to read "contemni spinam" with *moneo*, i.e. "she warns that the thorn is despised..."?

Comment: I don't think it means 'she warns that the thorn should be despised' in the same way that the first part means 'she warns that (one?) should use beauty,' if that's what you're asking. It's indirect statement, indicating something she says in the course of issuing her warning; it's separate from the infinitive (uti) that gives the actual substance of the warning and is equivalent to ut utatur (or utaris, utamur/, or whatever is meant to be extrapolated from context as the subject). Caesar, e.g., does this sort of thing all the time, but usually with a verb of ordering instead of warning.

Comment: Wait, why is *cecidere* indicative, though?

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Were you expecting the imperfect subjunctive? I think it's one of those historical-present things; axiomatic, accepted truths, written in the present. Therefore, for the present (and future) cum = "when" selects the indicative. Most interesting, yesterday, Allen & Greenough section 463 on the  "Historical Infinitive"--just to add to the confusion!!

Comment: @tony I was expecting a subjunctive because it's indirect speech. Neither the historical present nor the historical infinitive seem pertinent, seeing that *cecidere* is neither present nor an infinitive.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: The infinitive is "caedere", I should have checked. Allen & Greenough section 545: "A temporal clause with 'cum', 'when' and some past tense of the indicative dates or defines the time at which the action of the main verb occurred." e.g. "et [lituo] regiones direxit cum urbem condidit" (Div. 1. 30) = "he traced with it the quarters [of the sky] at the time he founded the city".

Comment: @tony I believe the infinite is *cadere*. I'm sure *cum* often stands with the indicative, but not in indirect speech. Maybe I'll ask a question about this passage.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: Is it a metre thing; perfect subjunctive, "ceciderint", wouldn't have scanned? Therefore, a grammatical violation is allowed.

Comment: @Sebastian Koppehel: In A & G section 583, subordinate clauses in indirect speech take the indicative if the clause is true; an explanation of something; worthy of emphasis (all of which may cover almost everything). Is this the answer; if not, are you still going to ask a supplementary question?